# In flutter How do i convert 2018-12-03T15:42:00Z to real date and time

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I convert this format `2018-12-03T15:42:00Z` to real readable yMd and time also? Please mention with example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` has a `parse` method for that:

```
DateTime.parse('2018-12-03T15:42:00Z')
```

or `tryParse` if you don't want an exception when the string is not in the correct format

```
DateTime.tryParse('2018-12-03T15:42:00Z')
```

Comment: It's working super Sir. Thank you very much for your help. God bless you @Gunter Zochbauer :)